# Trying to return the rows between two dates in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, finance

The code runs but I am trying to append a value from one dataframe to another and it returns empty so it basically doenst do anything.

```
for x in date_index_list:
    if x == 0:
        holder_dataframe = df[(df['Closing_date'] <= cash_flow_matrix.loc[x, 'Date'])]
        cash_flow_matrix.loc[x,'Negative_cashflow'] = - holder_dataframe.deployment.sum()
    else:
        holder_dataframe = df[(df['Closing_date'] <= cash_flow_matrix.loc[x,'Date']) & (df['Closing_date'] > cash_flow_matrix.loc[x - 1 ,'Date'])]
        cash_flow_matrix.loc[x,'Negative_cashflow'] = - holder_dataframe.deployment.sum()
```

Comment: Could you please provide your dataframe data and expected output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.